# Websocket: java.nio.BufferOverflowException exception

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I've a very strange exception on simple request/response to my server. I tested it when my site is used only by me, and the size of the response shouldn't exceed a few kilobytes.

***Question:*** What does that mean? Where should I try to fix it?

***Code:***

```
public class Peer implements WebSocketListener {

  private org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session session;

  public void sendResponse(Response response) {
        try {
            String stringifiedResponse = Utils.objectToJson(response); //just simple fasterxml mapping                
            if (stringifiedResponse.length() > 30000) {
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(Peer.class).debug("Big Response = " + stringifiedResponse);
            }
            session.getRemote().sendString(stringifiedResponse); //BufferOverflowException!!!
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do something!
        }
    }

  public void onWebSocketConnect(org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        this.session.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(2097152);
        this.session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageSize(2097152);
        this.session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(2097152);
        this.session.getPolicy().setInputBufferSize(2097151);
        Engine.addPeer(this);
  }
}
```

***Stacktrace:***

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension.outgoingFrame(PerMessageDeflateExtension.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.outgoingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.uncheckedSendFrame(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:297)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.blockingWrite(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.sendString(WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java:380)
        at com.levi9.levirs.core.Peer.sendResponse(Peer.java:48)
        at com.levi9.levirs.communication.user.UserRequestHandler$Login.handle(UserRequestHandler.java:42)
        at com.levi9.levirs.core.Peer.onWebSocketText(Peer.java:33)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextMessage(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextFrame(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.AbstractExtension.nextIncomingFrame(AbstractExtension.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension.nextIncomingFrame(PerMessageDeflateExtension.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension.incomingFrame(PerMessageDeflateExtension.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.read(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:500)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to findout what could be wrong. Are you going some encoding / decoding?

Comment: I'm not sure how jetty library works, but I suspect its to do with encoding. Are there methods to send byte array, you shall try that?

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy I don't think it linked with encoding due the fact that it reproduces not always and that it works well for a moment. I inclined to think that it appears after I change jetty version to `9.1.1.v20140108`